# How to set a value of input type after it was created

Tags: php

I have a basic question which I cant find an answer to.

i have an input text

I want to change the value by1 every time i click the button.

so, when I make a new soldier, i want it to be shown in the soldiers count.

I started programming in PhP recently.

In Java, command Im looking for would be some setText or something like that.

Comment: do you add "soldiers" to a database when you click the button? seeing as you provided no code we dont know where you are in your scrpit or what you have tried

Comment: Hmm, ok let me redefine  a question:

how to ++ a form's value every time i press the button?

if the starting value is 0, i press the button the form's value changes to 1, then 2 and so on...

that forms is also visible on the site, all the time

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea:

You specifically mentioned PHP so I'll give you a PHP example:
This is at the top of every page you want the form on...

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['soldiers']))
    $_SESSION['soldiers'] = 0;

include('form_process.php');
```

Then in form_process.php:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['soldiers']) && is_numeric($_POST['soldiers']))
        {
            if($_POST['soldiers'] == $_SESSION['soldiers'])
                $_SESSION['soldiers'] ++;
            else
                $_SESSION['soldiers'] = $_POST['soldiers'];
        }

?>
<form id="soldiers" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="soldiers" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['soldiers']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I would do this in html and jquery personally, but you asked for PHP so here you go.

Why use sessions? Cause you said the form is on every page so you need to maintain a constant number throughout the session. Better to use a database so the number is constant across all people who may be viewing the site, but you didn't specify that in your question.

I myself don't know what value something like this could be in the state it is in. To me it sounds like you wanted a javascript type way to just update the html of an element on click, which makes a little more sense than incrementing an input value the user can just manually overwrite to begin with. But hey, the beauty of programming is it never needs to make sense to anybody per say, so long as you get whatever you want out of it.